# Why is my ip unreachable when I do a trace route?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, openstack, virtual-network

I am trying to create a virtual network of one instance and one router connected to each other in openstack. So it means that this virtual network is inside my home network. My home network is 10.0.0.0/24, its gateway is 10.0.0.138. Openstack is running on 10.0.0.63 on a virtual machine in my home network. The virtual router has an external interface ip of 10.0.0.253 but pings to it are unsuccessful, why is this so?:

```
C:\Users\daisk>tracert 10.0.0.253

Tracing route to 10.0.0.253 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1  DESKTOP-xxxxxxx.gateway [10.0.0.12]  reports: Destination host unreachable.

Trace complete.
```

Why is my ip unreachable here?

I ultimately want to be able to access the virtual instance inside the virtual network which is inside my home network from the internet.

I'm trying to adapt this for my own situation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqFpyubsYfE

running: 'ip a' gives this:

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1700 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:f0:19:9b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.63/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
       valid_lft 85977sec preferred_lft 85977sec
    inet6 fe80::5fb4:dc85:6a52:bb09/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ovs-system: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ee:d3:37:d8:18:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: br-ex: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:0a:7c:98:42:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br-tun: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 86:f9:07:a3:f7:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
18: br-int: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1450 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c6:4b:cc:53:9a:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
20: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:bf:ad:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
21: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:bf:ad:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
49: tap459b4a9f-12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc fq_codel master ovs-system state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:16:3e:f9:20:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc16:3eff:fef9:20f0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Have you checked security-groups?

Comment: My guess is that the external network that you configured in your cloud is not connected to the outside world. How did you create that cloud? Can you run `ip a` on the cloud's host and add the output to the question?

Comment: I have solved it by redoing everything and following the answer in this web page: https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/112760/router-external-interface-is-down/

Now my problem is that I can't successfully ping the internet nor the external network gateway.

Comment: The ip address output shows that *br-ex* has no IP address. I believe this explains your original problem, at least partially. Can you explain your new problem better, perhaps create a new question? I understand that the router can now be accessed from outside, but OpenStack instances can access neither internet nor router's gateway.